# Sketch the graph of a function that satisfies all of the stated conditions

Tags: calculus

The conditions are:

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=2$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2^-}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2^+}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}f(x)=-\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow2^+}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow3^-}f(x)=2$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow3^+}f(x)=4$

Comment: What are your attempts of the problem so far? Is there a particular condition you are having trouble with?

Comment: Do you know about limits, asymptotes, and end behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Well, given

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=1$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=2$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2^-}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2^+}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}f(x)=-\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow2^+}f(x)=\infty$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow3^-}f(x)=2$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow3^+}f(x)=4$

The first two tell you what the end behavior is, i.e., there is a horizontal asymptote at $y=1$ to the left and $y=2$ to the right.

The third and fourth indicate a vertical asymptote at $x=-2$ that is approaching $\infty$ from both left and right of $x=-2$.

The fifth indicates a vertical asymptote toward $-\infty$ approaching $x=1$ from the left.

The sixth indicates a vertical asymptote toward $\infty$ approaching $x=2$ from the right.

The last two indicate a jump discontinuity where $f(x)$ approaches $2$ from the left of $x=3$ and $4$ from the right of $x=3$.

If you start sketching approximations of all of these together you should get a clear picture of your function.